# Create DML, DDL, DQL user in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

I need to create 3 users with different DML, DDL, DQL on newly created clean Database in PostgreSQL.

- DML should have SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE
- DDL should have CREATE, DROP, ALTER, TRUNCATE, INSERT
- DQL should have SELECT

all of this in standard scheme public.
Important is that user inherit right on newly created tables by DDL user.

users ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dql-dml-dcl-tcl-commands/

I did some coding but I'm pretty new in PostgreSQL and it didn't work :(

The main problem was that I cannot perform GRANT or REVOKE on CREATE, DROP, ALTER, TRUNCATE :(

Can someone help please?

Maybe you have something similar already prepared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup you want, can be done to some extent. However these privileges are controlled on *schema* level, not on database level.

Assuming you have a schema `app_schema` for which this should be defined, you can do the following:

First create the users:

```
create user ddl with password '***';
create user dml with password '***';
create user dql with password '***';
```

Then create the schema:

```
create schema app_schema;
```

Then allow the ddl user to create objects:

```
grant create,usage on schema app_schema to ddl;
```

Then change the default privileges on the schema, so that every table (or view, or sequence ...) created by the `ddl` user is accessible by the dml and dql users:

```
alter default privileges 
   for role ddl
   grant select,update,delete on tables
   to dml;

alter default privileges 
   for role ddl
   grant select on tables
   to dql;
```

This will affect all *future* tables created in the schema by the user `ddl`.

The owner of the tables automatically has the privileges to INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE or TRUNCATE the tables.

I have never tried this, but it seems possible to revoke the UPDATE and SELECT privileges:

```
alter default privileges 
  for role ddl
  in schema app_schema
  revoke update,select,delete on tables
  from ddl;
```

If there are already tables in the schema, you need to grant the desired privileges for them:

```
grant select,insert,update,delete on all tables 
  in schema app_schema
  to dml;

grant select on all tables 
  in schema app_schema
  to dql;
```

Comment: Hi i executed below:  
`CREATE user dml with NOCREATEDB password 'testdml'; 
CREATE user ddl with NOCREATEDB password 'testddl';
CREATE user dql with NOCREATEDB password 'testdql';

create schema test_schema; 

grant create,usage on schema test_schema to ddl;


alter default privileges 
   for role ddl
   grant select,update,delete on tables
   to dml;
   
  alter default privileges 
   for role ddl
   grant select on tables 
   to dql;
   
  alter default privileges 
  for role ddl
  in schema test_schema
  revoke update,select,delete on tables
  from ddl;`

Comment: Using ddl user i created test table in that scheme. 
`create table test_schema.candidatesddl (
    candidate_id int generated always as identity,
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100) not null,
    email varchar(255) not null unique,
    phone varchar(25) not null,
    primary key(candidate_id)
);`

Inserted record:   

`INSERT INTO test_schema.candidatesddl(first_name, last_name, email, phone)
VALUES('Joe','Com','joe.com@example.com','408-111-2222');`

Comment: And i'm really sorry for formatting i'm  new to stackoverflow and cannot get it done properly :(

Comment: i checked **CREATE**, **DROP** , with user **DML** and i cannot perform that actions which are good and is planned.

i checked also user **DQL** it doesn`t have any permissions also on scheme he cannot perform any actions, but also cannot perform **SELECT**

Comment: Then relog into **DML** account and tried to perform SELECT: `select * from test_schema.candidatesddl` And got an error.
Same for **UPDATE, DELETE**. I checked **CREATE, DROP ** with user **DML** and i cannot perform that actions which are good and as planned.

I checked also user **DQL** it doesn`t have any permissions also on scheme, he cannot perform any actions, but also cannot perform **SELECT**

Seems that inheritance of permissions on created tables by **DDL** is not working as expected. 

Am i doing smth wrong ?

Comment: anything you can help me with @a_horse_with_no_name ?

Comment: Solution found you need to add next thing for 2 accounts:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test_schema TO dml;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test_schema TO dql;